# Can PHP's PDO be limited to a single query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

PHP's PDO allows multiple querys to be executed at once, either via the query() method or as a prepared statement. Both of the following examples work:

```
// Two SQL queries
$query = "SELECT * FROM table; DROP table;"

// Execute via query()
$pdo->query($query);

// Execute via prepared statement
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

Is there any way to limit PDO to a single query at a time, much like the mysql_query() function is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a more up-to-date answer to this question.

The old way of preventing multi query execution was to disable emulated prepares, however this was only applicable to the `PDO::prepare()` method. In newer versions of PHP (>= 5.5.21 and >= 5.6.5), a new constant has been introduced to disable this multi query execution in both `PDO::prepare()` and `PDO::query()`. (Constants aren't usually added in patch versions, but this was done due to the severity of a [Drupal SQL injection attack](https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-005) brought about by this capability).

The new constant is `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MULTI_STATEMENTS` and **must** be set on object creation (as the fourth argument to the PDO constructor) - setting it on a pre-existing object with `PDO::setAttribute()` will not work.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=_;dbname=_', '', '', [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MULTI_STATEMENTS => false]);
```

Comment: I didn't find anything about PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MULTI_STATEMENTS in PHP documentation. but I tried it and it works;

Comment: I wasn't aware that it hadn't been document yet. I've added it to [MySQL's constants page](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) - it should be viewable in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 7):

Mmm, there's a way of achieving this by disabling the emulation of prepared statements in PDO to make it use the native mysql API instead (multi-querying is not supported in server-side prepared statements):

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

However, one of the drawbacks of this option is that the query cache is lost.

Comment: "Beginning with 5.1.17, prepared statements use the query cache under certain conditions" - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html

Comment: There's no way to prevent it via the query() method though?

Comment: Not that I know, unless you use some custom code to previously filter the query string.