# How to Perform SQL Injection making a SELECT statement UPDATE or INSERT rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL Injection - Use SELECT query to UPDATE/DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759603/mysql-injection-use-select-query-to-update-delete)

So I have found in my site bug that allows to perform sql injection
`http://mysite.com/script.php?id=1 union select 1,2,3` will output all fields that has Id property equal to one plus one additional row with 1,2,3. I know that I have to validate user input to close my bug.

However my question is quite another. Is it possible to perform update query or insert query? I am able to comment query using --, however I cannot use multiple statements that are delimited by `;`. So is it possible to perform update query in my case. I can show PHP code and SQL query if needed.

```
$sql    = "SELECT id, title, text from table where cId=$val";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$array  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
//echo rows in table
```

Comment: Yes please - please always show code where it is available.

Comment: It might be possible if there are predefined functions available in your database that take arbitrary SQL as input. I don't know if any such thing exists, or what database might have that in a standard library, but it is possible. It might be called via `SELECT my_func('DELETE FROM ...');`

Comment: Use PDO/mysqli with parametrised queries. That way you don't have to worry about code injection.

Comment: (I rolled back your edit (and then re-applied your code change) as you accidentally reverted minor edits I made to your question. Please refresh your page before making edits, for this reason).

Comment: @Halfer Sure, thank you. As I understood update query here is almost impossible? Yes?

Comment: @Seeker: Why should anybody tell you? If we say, it's not possible, do you feel save then? If we say, it's possible, what then?

Comment: From the manual: _mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported)_ so that's a good start. Notwithstanding, you should definitely fix this issue - I wouldn't leave it as it is just because you feel 'safe enough'.

Comment: @hakre if that's not possible then nothing critical if user can read my table. However if not, user can perform something like `DROP database wow`.

Comment: _nothing critical if user can read my table_ - but that will permit users to look up each other's data, assuming you have such a thing on your site.

Comment: @Seeker: Well, the actual problem you face is located elsewhere. You think it's not critical while in reality you've just found an existing problem. Fix it! Anything else is just making you weak to care about important things.

Comment: There are other interesting things that can be done besides insert/update - Denial of Service using `SELECT BENCHMARK(99999999, some_query)`, seeing your data structure using `SELECT FROM information_schema`, dumping data to files and consuming all the space using `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from [MySQL Injection - Use SELECT query to UPDATE/DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759603/mysql-injection-use-select-query-to-update-delete)
all that is **protecting you is a limitation of mysql_query**. I would not rely on this, and in particular not that it remains this way over time. You should never rely on a feature to be disabled by default. **Maybe the next version** already allows statements such as.

```
SELECT id, title, text from table where cId=1; DROP table table
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope it is not possible. Most probably you ar running **mysql_query**, that would not allow multiple queries to be run in one pass. And hence if your query starts with SELECT (as it does), it would not allow any UPDATE injection

Edit: Use  **mysql_real_escape_string** on your input even then

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is irrelevant to SQL injections

Comment: @YourCommonSense It’s not completely irrelevant but it’s not always applicable either. As always, it depends.

Answer (score 0):

By default this should not be possible. Although there are options for `mysql_query` to run multiple statements in one string since MySQL 5.0 which you have to set with `mysql_set_server_option`.

Please consider changing your statement command like this to use `mysql_real_escape_string`:

```
$q = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT id, title, text from table where cId = " . mysql_real_escape_string($val)));
```

At the very best you change your code to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-mysql.php) since all mysql_* functions are officially deprecated.