# Could execute an UPDATE clause in WHERE?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I'm learning SQL injection and I built a web application(PHP + MYSQL(5.6)) without protection of SQL injection.

In brief, my web application use

```
SELECT * FROM XXX.USER WHERE user_name='${USERNAME}' AND password='${PASSWORD}'
```

to handle login(if that sql returns only 1 row, then login succeed).

At the beginning, I found input USERNAME `Sayakiss' --` then my SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM XXX.USER WHERE user_name='Sayakiss' -- ' AND password='${PASSWORD}'
```

By that way, attacker can login as `Sayakiss` without password.

Then I find something more interesting(`select` clause can be in `if` function) -- attacker input USERNAME as

```
Sayakiss' and if((select ascii(mid(z,p,1)) from x.y limit n,1)=c,1,0) --
```

This can check character the ascii of the character of `p` position of `n`-th row of the column `z` of table `x.y` equals `c` or not.

If attacker login succeed, then he knows the ascii of the character equals `c`.

So attacker can get everything of my database by a enumeration!

Now I wonder, how to (if it's possible) execute a update query to write database by a similar way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe so, that a attacker can make an update, probably will be needing names of table and fields to run it correctly.
I think the query would be something like
`'Sayakiss'; UPDATE table_name SET field1=new-value1, field2=new-value2
 WHERE user_name='Sayakiss'; --`
[Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759603/mysql-injection-use-select-query-to-update-delete) and 
[Some more](https://osandamalith.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/injection-in-insert-update-and-delete-statements/)

Comment: I think it would better if there is only one sql statement, because I think in most real cases will fail if you input multiple statement...